# Error While Pasting Image to Worksheet Cells

Tags: c#, excel, emgucv

I am working on a face recognition program using emguCV.

Right now, I am writing a program to write the test results in an excel worksheet.

Here are the code that I used to paste the test result:

```
Image a = imageBoxTesting.Image.Bitmap;                    
Image b = imageBoxTraining.Image.Bitmap;

                Clipboard.SetImage(a);
                cellRngImg = (Range)ws.Cells[rowCount, 1];
                ws.Paste(cellRngImg, a);

                ws.Cells[2][rowCount] = testingLabel;

                Clipboard.SetImage(b);
                cellRngImg2 = (Range)ws.Cells[rowCount, 3];
                ws.Paste(cellRngImg2, b);

                Clipboard.Clear();
                cellRngImg.Clear();
                cellRngImg2.Clear();

                ws.Cells[4][rowCount] = predictionLabel;
                ws.Cells[5][rowCount] = ed;
                ws.Cells[6][rowCount] = valid;
                ws.Cells[7][rowCount] = maxDistance;
rowCount++;
```

The code above  is put in a loop until every available testing images are tested.

The error seems to occur on either of this line:

```
ws.Paste(cellRngImg, a);
ws.Paste(cellRngImg2, b);
```

And the error occurs randomly, never at the same iterations. On one run, it could occur at the 3rd iteration, on another run it could occur at the 17th iteration.

I have tried running VS as administrator, but it doesn't seem to affect anything.

Please help!
Thank you!

EDIT
The error message:
    An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occured in Eigenface.exe
    Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Comment: It's really hard to track down problems when they occur randomly on the same data set.  Maybe take a look at your memory usage and see if it's somehow related.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Where can I look at the memory usage?

Comment: Thank me by upticking me!  I'm sure there are people way smarter than me who have better tools but I use the Task Manager.  Also -- are you using the same data set and getting errors in random places or are you using different data sets?  Are the images all the same size?

Comment: Same dataset, all images are 80 by 80, and the errors indeed occured randomly, sometimes even not occurring at all. I've take a look at the memory usage and I think it's highly unlikely that it's related because the memory usage didn't even reach 50M.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I have managed to resolve it.

It looks like there is some lock in the Paste operation which may require time to be released.

I have created the following code for retry which resolved my problem:

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(picture, false);
bool pasteResult = false;
while (pasteResult == false)
{
    try
    {
        excelSheet.Paste(cellRngImg, picture);
        pasteResult = true;
    }
    catch
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
Clipboard.Clear();
```